# Rails engine's static assets not being served in host app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines

I'm working on a Rails engine. The engine includes some static JS/CSS in its `public` folder, and I want these assets to be merged into and served by the host application.

I added this to my `engine.rb` file:

```
initializer "static assets" do |app|
  app.middleware.insert_before(::ActionDispatch::Static, ::ActionDispatch::Static, "#{root}/public")
end
```

Interestingly, when I run the dummy app within the Rails engine itself, *or* install the engine inside a separate app on my filesystem via `path`:

```
gem 'my-engine', path: '~/my-engine`
```

everything works. But once I publish to RubyGems and install in another app via

```
gem 'my-engine'
```

the static assets all 404.

Any ideas on how to diagnose? Is there anything else I need to do within the host app to ensure the static assets are getting pulled in + being served? It's not a production environment thing, because it doesn't even work in development.

Comment: What version of rails was this? Rails 4?

Answer (score 4):

I forgot to `public` to the files config option in my `.gemspec`:

```
Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  ..
  s.files = Dir["{app,config,db,lib,public}/**/*", "MIT-LICENSE", "Rakefile", "README.rdoc"]
```

Everything works now!

Comment: i edit engine.rb and .gemspec, but it still show error:  http://localhost:3000/blog/slider/slider-1.js 404 (Not Found). Have i miss any settings?